# Color variables only work individually and not grouped

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to grey out check-boxes on my side panel list.

When I write out the code individually, this works. However, working with SCSS, I am trying to group the elements together and separating the classes with commas but no result.

```
.checkbox-event-type-trainings
.checkbox-event-type-medizinisch
.checkbox-event-type-spiele
.checkbox-event-type-tests
.checkbox-event-type-andere
.checkbox-container .checkmark {
  background-color: var(--dark-04);
}
```

My variables file.

```
:root {
    --color-white: #fff;
    --color-light-grey: grey;
    --color-medium-dark-grey:#282c34 ;
    --color-medium-dark-grey2: #32323b;
    --color-dark-grey: #24242b;
  --color-dark-grey-ten-percent-darker: #191922;
    --color-black: #000;
    --color-yellow: #fbc337;
    --color-yellow-ten-percent-darker: #e2b031;
    --color-green: #43ac43;
    --main-bg-color: var(--color-medium-dark-grey);
    --navbar-bg-color: var(--color-dark-grey);
    --calendar-border-color: var(--color-dark-grey);
    --calendar-background-color: var(--color-medium-dark-grey2);
    --base-font-size: 12px;
    --primary-font-color: var(--color-light-grey);
    --secondary-font-color: var(--color-white);
    --highlight-font-color: var(--color-yellow);
    --highlight-font-color-ten-percent-darker: var(--color-yellow-ten-percent-darker);


    /* events*/

    --event-type-trainings-color: rgba(67, 172, 67, 1);
    --event-type-trainings-color-with-opacity: rgba(67, 172, 67, 0.5);
    --event-border-type-trainings: solid 1px var(--event-type-trainings-color-with-opacity);
    --event-bg-color-type-trainings: rgba(67, 172, 67, 0.2);
    --event-bg-color-type-trainings-selected: rgba(67, 172, 67, 0.4);

    --event-type-medizinisch-color: rgba(189, 0, 38, 1);
    --event-type-medizinisch-color-with-opacity: rgba(189, 0, 38, 0.5);
    --event-border-type-medizinisch: solid 1px var(--event-type-medizinisch-color-with-opacity);
    --event-bg-color-type-medizinisch: rgba(189, 0, 38, 0.2);
    --event-bg-color-type-medizinisch-selected: rgba(189, 0, 38, 0.4);

    --event-type-spiele-color: rgba(251, 195, 55, 1);
    --event-type-spiele-color-with-opacity: rgba(251, 195, 55, 0.5);
    --event-border-type-spiele: solid 1px var(--event-type-spiele-color-with-opacity);
    --event-bg-color-type-spiele: rgba(251, 195, 55, 0.2);
    --event-bg-color-type-spiele-selected: rgba(251, 195, 55, 0.4);

    --event-type-tests-color: rgba(95, 151, 250, 1);
    --event-type-tests-color-with-opacity: rgba(95, 151, 250, 0.5);
    --event-border-type-tests: solid 1px var(--event-type-tests-color-with-opacity);
    --event-bg-color-type-tests: rgba(95, 151, 250, 0.2);
    --event-bg-color-type-tests-selected: rgba(95, 151, 250, 0.4);

    --event-type-andere-color: rgba(215, 215, 215, 1);
    --event-type-andere-color-with-opacity: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.5);
    --event-border-type-andere: solid 1px var(--event-type-andere-color-with-opacity);
    --event-bg-color-type-andere: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.2);
    --event-bg-color-type-andere-selected: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.4);
}
```

_variables.css

```
$color-white: #fafafa;
$color-grey-light: #ffffff;

$color-yellow: #fbc337;
$color-yellow-light: #f3c95f;

$color-primary: #292930;
$color-primary-darker: #24242b;
$color-secondary: #32323b;

//    --------------------------------     from Django project      ----------------------------------------

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind);

//Fonts
$font-hint: "Hind";

// Colors
$color-dark-gray: #2d2d2d;
$color-light-gray: #4f4f4f;
$color-custom-white: rgba(250, 250, 250, 1);
$color-custom-yellow: #fbc337;
$color-white-opacity-80: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
$color-white-opacity-50: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
$color-white-opacity-30: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.3);
$color-white-opacity-10: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.1);
$color-light-gray-opacity-75: rgba(215, 215, 215, 0.75);
$color-black-opacity-10: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
$color-black-opacity-16: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
$color-black-opacity-30: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
$color-black-opacity-50: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
$color-gray-border: #707070;
$color-dark-purple: #24242b;
$color-dark-purple-opacity-50: rgba(36, 36, 43, 0.5);
$color-light-purple: #32323b;
$color-neutral-purple: #292930;
$color-neutral-purple-opacity-90: rgba(41, 41, 48, 0.9);
$color-neutral-purple-opacity-80: rgba(41, 41, 48, 0.8);
$color-doctor: #fb3771;
$color-trainer: #78b782;
$color-physio: #8ebfff;
$color-green-button: #74bd77;
$color-header-label: #525259;
$training-03: #43ac43;
$training-03-opacity-30: rgba(67, 172, 67, 0.3);
$medical-01: #fc4445;
$medical-02: #bd0026;
$medical-03-opacity-30: rgba(252, 68, 69, 0.3);
$playerdev-01: #5f97fa;
$playerdev-01-opacity-30: rgba(95, 151, 250, 0.3);
$shade-dark: #d7d7d7;
$gold-03: #fff6a7;
$dark-04: #525259;

// Common styles
$border-radius: 5px;
$margin-between-element: 15px;
$margin-end-of-page: 50px;

$navbar-height: 5rem;
```

When I type them out individually (.checkbox-event-type-andere .checkbox-container .checkmark {
  background-color: ;
}) for example, it will work but not in a group. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but have you tried separating each classname with a comma in your group declaration ?

```css
.checkbox-event-type-trainings,
.checkbox-event-type-medizinisch,
.checkbox-event-type-spiele,
.checkbox-event-type-tests,
.checkbox-event-type-andere,
.checkbox-container, .checkmark {
  background-color: var(--dark-04);
}
```

Like this, may work (not tested though)

Comment: Yes, tried that earlier but still do not seem to have any joy with it unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You should add `,` between the class names otherwise you look for an element which has all the classes

Something like

```
.checkbox-event-type-trainings,
.checkbox-event-type-medizinisch,
.checkbox-event-type-spiele,
.checkbox-event-type-tests,
.checkbox-event-type-andere,
.checkbox-container,
.checkmark {
  background-color: var(--dark-04);
}
```

or if the `checkmark` classname is applied the listed classes :

```
.checkbox-event-type-trainings,
.checkbox-event-type-medizinisch,
.checkbox-event-type-spiele,
.checkbox-event-type-tests,
.checkbox-event-type-andere,
.checkbox-container {
  .checkmark{
    background-color: var(--dark-04);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried that just now. Unfortunately, that didn't work so still trying to see what the issue could be.